# Custom bootloader issues

Tags: assembly, x86, disk, utility, bootloader

Im trying to write a bootloader for a Hobby OS and have it working great. 
Nothing Special, just prints a line of text:

```
BITS 16
ORG 0

start: jmp main


OEM         db "Test OS "           
BytesPerSector:     DW 512
SectorsPerCluster:  DB 1
ReservedSectors:    DW 1
NumberOfFATs:   DB 2
RootEntries:    DW 224
TotalSectors:   DW 2880
Media:      DB 0xf8  
SectorsPerFAT:  DW 9
SectorsPerTrack:    DW 18
HeadsPerCylinder:   DW 2
HiddenSectors:  DD 0
TotalSectorsBig:    DD 0
DriveNumber:        DB 0
Unused:         DB 0
ExtBootSignature:   DB 0x29
SerialNumber:   DD 0xa0a1a2a3
VolumeLabel:    DB "HOBBY  OS  "
FileSystem:         DB "FAT12   "



main:
    ;Adjust code Seg.
    cli
    mov ax, 0x07c0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    ;Set up Stack
    mov ax, 0x0000
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0xFFFF
    sti

    mov si, msg
    call print

print:

    .charLoop:

        lodsb
        or al,al
        jz .done
        mov ah, 0x0E
        int 0x10
    .done
        ret

msg db "Hello World",13,10,0
```

Im compiling with

```
nasm -f bin loader.asm -o loader.bin
dd if=loader.bin of=floppy.img bs=512 count=1 seek=0
```

I've read that the first 446 bytes are the boot code and bytes 447 - 509 is the partition table.
I tried then using:

```
dd if=loader.bin of=floppy.img bs=446 count=1 seek=0
```

to try to prevent the partition table from being overwritten but still no cigar.

Im using a Mac with OSX and Testing the OS with VirtualBox

I can run the floppy.img in VBox and the code works fine, but when I try to install the bootloader onto a FAT 16 Formatted disk, OSX can't seem read the disk image any more as if it became unformatted.

The exact message out of disk utility is `Unable to attach image "floppy.img."(No Mountable File Systems)` Even though I just formatted the disk with a FAT 16 file system.

Unfortunatly since this is my first post, I can't give you a picture.

I would really appreciate any help. Disk structure really isn't my forte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're using `dd`, try adding the `conv=notrunc` option. This forces it to not try to truncate the file, but rather, just overwrite the parts you specified.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would have never guessed